# converting teaming to bonding

Tags: networking, rhel

RHEL 7 contains `bond2team` tool but it doesn't contains opposite `team2bond` tool. I need to convert my teaming files to bonding (please don't ask why, this is for testing purposes). This is my teaming config:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-team0
DEVICE=team0
DEVICETYPE=Team
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
TEAM_CONFIG='{"runner": { "name": "lacp", "active": true, "fast_rate": true, "tx_hash": ["eth", "ipv4"]}, "link_watch": {"name": "ethtool"}}'
```

I've tried to write "similar" bonding config:

```
DEVICE=bond0
TYPE=Bond
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 miimon=100 xmit_hash_policy=layer2+3"
```

Then, to proove that my config is the same I've used `bond2team` tool and this is output:

```
DEVICE=bond0
TYPE=Bond
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
DEVICETYPE="Team"
TEAM_CONFIG='{ "runner" : {  "name" : "lacp",  "tx_hash" : [ "eth", "l3" ] }, "link_watch" : {  "name" : "ethtool" } }'
```

As you can see resulted "teaming" file doesn't match exactly my teaming file. The question is - how should I modify bonding file, so after applying `bond2team` I got something like my current teaming file? Currently `"active": true, "fast_rate": true,` is missing and `"eth", "l3"` instead of `"eth", "ipv4"`

Answer (score 0):

In bonding equivalent option are **lacp_rate** and **xmit_hash_policy**
You can configure it in same file like this:

```
BONDING_OPTS="mode=4 miimon=100 lacp_rate=1 xmit_hash_policy=2"
```